# How do I get state or props into TabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'd like to get user image into the tabBarIcon just like Instagram does it. I can't figure out the way to do it.

I tried getting the state but on the init of the app the state is empty.

I've tried like

```js
const store = store.getState().user
```

but it's undefined on app init

I have MainTabNavigator.js

```js
ProfileStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: () => {
        return null
    },
    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
        <Image source={{uri: ???}}/>
    )
}

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    HomeStack,
    SearchStack,
    DashboardStack,
    ProfileStack,
});

TabNavigator.path = '';


export default TabNavigator;
```

I can't get the props or state since this isn't a class

Comment: Where is the path of the user image?

Comment: It's just on my localhost but it doesn't matter... I got it working and I'll post the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple.... I don't know why I didn't think of it earlier.

The trick was to create a component that would get the state from redux and when the state changes after the init, the state would finally have the Object and there the image path

```js
ProfileStack.navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: () => {
        return null
    },
    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
        <BottomTabImage focused={focused} />
    )
}
```

See i changed it to BottomTabImage which is just a component

And this is the component file

BottomTabImage.js

```js
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class BottomTabImage extends Component {
    render() {
        const uri = this.props.auth.image !== undefined ?`http://localhost/storage/creator_images/${this.props.auth.image)}`: '';
        return <Image style={styles.profileImage} source={{uri}} />
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    profileImage: {
        ...
    }
});

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        auth: state.user.auth
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(BottomTabImage)
```